# Problem regarding Word Searcher Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

My code seems to throw this error :java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0 with using substring and string.charAt() methods

I've tried changing the values in the for loop and in arguments, so string index won't go past its intended values

```
public final class WordSearcher {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //String wordLibrary = args[0];
        //String puzzle = args[1];
        int j,k,l;
        String wordLibrary = "TEST,SAMPLE,OUTPUT";
        String puzzle = "TUPTUOELPMAS";
        String puzzleDup = puzzle;
        String[] wordstoFind = wordLibrary.split(",");
        int ifWordExists = 0;
        int puzzleLength = puzzle.length();

        for(k = 0; k< wordstoFind.length; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l< wordstoFind[k].length(); l++) {
                for(j=0; j< puzzleLength; j++) {

                    if(wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
                        ifWordExists++;
                        puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j+1,puzzleDup.length());
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            } 

            if( ifWordExists == wordstoFind[k].length()) 
                    System.out.println(wordstoFind[k]);


                ifWordExists = 0;
                System.out.println(puzzle);
                puzzleDup = puzzle;
        }

            for(k = 0; k< wordstoFind.length; k++) {
                for (l = 0; l< wordstoFind[k].length(); l++) {
                    for(j=puzzleLength-1; j> 0; j--) {

                        if(wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
                            ifWordExists++;
                            puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(0,j-1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }     
                } 

                if( ifWordExists == wordstoFind[k].length()) 
                    System.out.println(wordstoFind[k]);


                ifWordExists = 0;
                System.out.println(puzzle);
                puzzleDup = puzzle;
        }
    }
}
```

It's supposed to find words dispersed in a string passed as a command line argument. for example, XTXXXEXXXXXSXT should return TEST, if that is one of the words i have to find.

Comment: The stack trace will point you to the specific line of code. A debugger will allow you to trace through your code's execution and see where you are trying to use an index too large for the array you are referencing. If you aren't in a position to use a debugger, more printlns.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for(k = 0; k < wordstoFind.length; k++) {
    for (l = 0; l < wordstoFind[k].length(); l++) {
        for(j = 0; j < puzzleLength; j++) {
            if(wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
                ifWordExists++;
                puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j + 1, puzzleDup.length());
                                                ^^^^^
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
```

If `j` equals to `puzzleLength - 1`, `j + 1` will be out of the string's bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't really the code line:

```
puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j + 1, puzzleDup.length());
```

but rather the fact that you are iterating through the wrong Puzzle String at two specific locations (loops) within your code. Let's take the second ***inner*** FOR loop within the first set of Loops:

```
for(j = 0; j < puzzleLength; j++) {
    if(wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
        ifWordExists++;
        puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j + 1, puzzleDup.length());
        break;
    }
}
```

Here you are iterating through a length of The original Puzzle String but your are comparing the characters from the actual **word** to characters within the **puzzleDup** string. At first the **puzzleDup** variable will hold the original content of the actual Puzzle String but within the same loop you delete any found characters that will match a character from the **word** being tested. By doing this deletion it reduces the length of **puzzleDup** and because the **Puzzle String** will be longer than what **puzzleDup** will be the integer variable **j** will eventually go out of bounds of what **puzzleDup** is capable of handling therefore generating the **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

The bottom line....if you are going to be comparing **word** characters to **puzzleDup** characters and then modifying **puzzleDup** during the process then use **puzzleDup** in the loop declaration:

```
for (int j = 0; j < puzzleDup.length(); j++) {
    if (wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
        ifWordExists++;
        puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j + 1, puzzleDup.length());
        break;
    }
}
```

On another note, the following code line

```
puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(j + 1, puzzleDup.length());
```

is not really all that effective unless the first character of **puzzleDup** will always be the character being compared to from the **word**. What is to happen if it's the 3rd character in **puzzleDup**? Do you then wipe out the first three characters contained within **puzzleDup**? What if one of the characters you just wiped out is needed for the next **word** character? I believe the idea here would be to remove **only** the specific character in **puzzleDup** that made the match to the current character of **word**. This line should then be:

```
puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(0, j) + puzzleDup.substring(j + 1);
```

This line of code will remove from **puzzleDup** only the character that is equal to the character from the word currently being processed. This now leaves all other characters in **puzzleDup** to have the chance to be compared to. The entire inner loop should really look like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < puzzleDup.length(); j++) {
    if (wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
        ifWordExists++;
        puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(0, j) + puzzleDup.substring(j + 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

And in your other set of FOR loops further down in code, the second ***inner*** FOR loop should look something like this:

```
for (int j = puzzleDup.length() - 1; j > 0; j--) {
    if (wordstoFind[k].charAt(l) == puzzleDup.charAt(j)) {
        ifWordExists++;
        puzzleDup = puzzleDup.substring(0, j-1) + puzzleDup.substring(j);
        break;
    }
}
```

Below I provide a method which can demonstrates one way this particular task can be accomplished. In this example, you provide a comma (,) delimited **Words String** (just like you already do with your code example) and you also provide a Puzzle String. The method will return a List collection where each element of that list will contain:

- A line containing the actual shuffled Puzzle String;
- A line of dashes (-) to the same length of the puzzle String with the
  exception that matched characters from the puzzled string and
  characters from the word being processed are also within the line
  indicating exactly where in the puzzle string the matches were found;
- A line containing the actual Word that relates to the above result.

Here is the method:

```
public static List<String> findWordsInString(String wordsToLocate, String inputOrPuzzleString) {
    List<String> resultsList = new ArrayList<>();
    // With the following split regex, it doesn't matter 
    // how the words are comma delimited with regards to
    // spacing.
    String[] wordstoFind = wordsToLocate.split("\\s{0,},\\s{0,}");
    List<String> foundCharList;
    for (int k = 0; k < wordstoFind.length; k++) {
        String libWord = wordstoFind[k];
        /* The following flag is used to prevent a word from being
           found twice within the Puzzle String at different locations.
           If you actually want this feature then comment the below line
           and any code lines related to it.        */
        boolean wordFound = false;  
        foundCharList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int l = 0; l < libWord.length(); l++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputOrPuzzleString.length(); j++) {
                if (libWord.charAt(l) == inputOrPuzzleString.charAt(j)) {
                    // Found a character. Add it and its puzzle index (delimited with a Pipe character) to foundChar.
                    String foundChar = inputOrPuzzleString.substring(j, (j + 1)) + "|" + String.valueOf(j);
                    /* Make sure the Character at Index isn't already in foundCharList.
                       We're not allowed to use the same character at the same puzzle 
                       index more than once in any given word.         */
                    boolean alreadyHave = false;
                    for (String str : foundCharList) {
                        if (str.equals(foundChar)) {
                            alreadyHave = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    /* Make sure we need the character and it won't be a duplicate to the
                       word makeup. We do this by removing all the characters we've already 
                       found from a copy of the word we're working on then see which characters
                       are remaining. If the current character matches one of the remaining
                       then it's good to keep.         */
                    String tmpWord = libWord;
                    for (String strg : foundCharList) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < tmpWord.length(); x++) {
                            if (strg.split("\\|")[0].equals(tmpWord.substring(x, x + 1))) {
                                tmpWord = tmpWord.substring(0, x) + tmpWord.substring(x + 1);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (tmpWord.contains(Character.toString(inputOrPuzzleString.charAt(j))) && !alreadyHave) {
                        foundCharList.add(foundChar);
                    }
                }
                if (foundCharList.size() == libWord.length()) {
                    resultsList.add(showWordMakeupInString(foundCharList, libWord, inputOrPuzzleString));
                    foundCharList.clear();
                    wordFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                if (wordFound) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultsList;
}
```

This method also requires a satellite method named **showWordMakeupInString() which sets up the string lines to be placed in the returned List. You can of course modify all this to whatever way you like:

```
public static String showWordMakeupInString(List<String> list, String word, String puzzleString) {
    String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    String resultString = puzzleString + ls;
    String locations = String.join("", Collections.nCopies(puzzleString.length(), "-"));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String[] parts = list.get(i).split("\\|");
        char letter = parts[0].charAt(0);
        int atIndex = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        char[] puzzleChars = locations.toCharArray();
        puzzleChars[atIndex] = letter;
        locations = String.valueOf(puzzleChars);
    }
    resultString += locations + ls + word + ls;
    return resultString;
}
```

To use this method yo might do something like this:

```
// Create the WORD String...
String wordsToFind = "TEST,SAMPLE,OUTPUT,DOG,poop,HELLO,Who's Your Daddy";

// Create the PUZZLE String. Copy the WORD string and 
// paste it below then delete all the commas.
String puzzle = "TESTSAMPLEOUTPUTpoopHELLODOGWho's Your Daddy";

// Shuffle the PUZZLE String...really mix it up :) 
// The shuffleString() method is provided below.
puzzle = shuffleString(puzzle);

// Find the words within the WORD String within the PUZZLE String.
List<String> resultsList = findWordsInString(wordsToFind, puzzle);

// Display the Listed results to Console Window.
for(String strg : resultsList) {
    System.out.println(strg);
}
```

If you run the above example here is what you should see in the Console Window:

```
OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
--E--S--------T----T------------------------
TEST

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
--E--S-L--P------A-------------------------M
SAMPLE

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
O--U------P---T----T------------U-----------
OUTPUT

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
O---------------G------------------D--------
DOG

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
-o-------o---p--------------p---------------
poop

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
O-E----L-------------------L--------H-------
HELLO

OoEUWSOL oPOYpT'GAsTEdToaEdLp TyUoSDHPruLhDM
-o--W--- o--Y--'--s--d--a-d-- -y---D--ru-h--
Who's Your Daddy
```

Your results would of course be slightly different because the PUZZLE String is always shuffled differently on each run.

The **shuffleString()** method:

```
public String shuffleString(String input) {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        characters.add(c);
    }
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
    while (!characters.isEmpty()) {
        int randChar = (int) (Math.random() * characters.size());
        output.append(characters.remove(randChar));
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```